# Java Swing GUI: How to do a field that stores a keybind for a specific function and that - when clicked on it- asks for a key?

Tags: java, swing

sorry if the title is confusing but I just want something like in this video at 00:25
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReoXncADFFw&t=819s
I know I probably have to use keylistener and mouseadapter on a textfield or something but there are more things like: how do I do it that the field is not editable and can onlny be clicked like in the video etc?
I would appreciate your help very much :)! This is the last step for my gui to be complete :)

Comment: maybe you could first listen for the textField to be clicked, if it's clicked then you make the program listen for the next keyPressed, and store that key. I don't know if Swing can make a TextField do the clickable behavior, but you can use a button instead of TextField to achieve that, or design your own control

Comment: The key bindings are divorced from the text fields - that is, you don't "have to" binding the key strokes to the text fields.  When the binding is triggered, you could use it to update the text field programtically